# Publications Subscriptions Observe

Tags: meteor, observer-pattern, publish-subscribe, meteorite

I am working on a project where I want to show markers on a map.

These markers should be published from server with a viewport-constraint. That means that just markers are published which are inside the current users viewport.

The publication looks something like this:

```
//server
Meteor.publish('posts', function(bottom_left_x, bottom_left_y, upper_right_x, upper_right_y, limit) {

  return Posts.find({locs: {$geoWithin: {$box:
                                  [[bottom_left_x, bottom_left_y],
                                   [upper_right_x, upper_right_y]]}}},
                       {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: limit});
});
```

I always call this function via subscription when my map_center changes:

```
//client
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(event) {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();

  var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
  postsHandle= Meteor.subscribe('posts', sw.lat(), sw.lng(), ne.lat(), ne.lng(), 10);
});
```

Till now everything works fine.
Further i created a observefunction on posts, that renders a marker when "added" is called and remove when "removed" is called. Observe is very good to render new markers and to destroy the old ones

```
//client
Posts.find().observeChanges({
  added: function(post) {
  // when 'added' callback fires, add HTML element
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(post.locs.lat, post.locs.lng),
      postId: post._id,
      map: map,
    });
},removed .... and so on
```

That problem is that the observe-Callback is triggered on the whole Posts-Collection. But  i just want to show markers which are inside the users viewport. Thats why i normally have to do something like this:

```
//client
Posts.find({locs: {$geoWithin: {$box:
                                  [[bottom_left_x, bottom_left_y],
                                   [upper_right_x, upper_right_y]]}}},
                       {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: limit}).observeChanges({
```

But thats not possible. GeoWithin is not supported inside minimongo and it is not possible to call oberserve with a collection that has a limit.

Has anyone an idea how to accomplish this?
Maybe there is a way to push the posts i get from subcription directly to the map without using a query on minimongo?

Comment: How about publishing a new set which does this filtering on the server side and subscribe to it on the client? You will probably have to send the bounds somehow. Hmmm..might not work.

Comment: I already have a pulication on server side and it gets called every times my viewport changes. For example in viewport_1 i have 3 markers and viewport_2 delivers 2 makers than my postsCollection on client side contains 5 markers. Thats why i have to do some query via minimongo. But minimongo does not provide necessary parameters :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is so easy !

```
Meteor.autosubscribe( function () {
  Meteor.subscribe( 'chat', { room: Session.get( 'currentRoom' ) } );
} );
```

If you want to limit your subscription to the maps viewport with changing viewport-bounds, than you have to use autosubscribe. It seems that autosubscribe takes care of changing subscription-arguments :)

```
Meteor.autosubscribe( function () {
  var a = Session.get('bounds');
  if(a)
    Meteor.subscribe( 'posts', a.swlat, a.swlng, a.nelat, a.nelng, 5 );
} );
```